# How to use map in Haskell with a variable and a list

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, map-function, arity

I'm planning to write am map function which essentially takes in a variable and a list and returns a list.

I've tried to use standard map but from what I've seen it's in the format "map function list" when here I'm trying to pass in another argument which is another point.

```
data Point = {xCoord :: Int,
              yCoord :: Int}

movePoint :: Point -> Point -> Point
movePoint (Point x y) (Point xMove yMove)
    = Point (x + xMove)  (y + yMove)

 // Add a "vector" to a list of points
movePoints :: [Point] -> Point -> [Point]
movePoints = error "Not yet"
```

For example, if I have a vector for example (2,2) and I have a list of Points such as [(-2,1),(0,0), (5,4) etc.] I want to use map to add (2,2) to all the Points in the list and return a list of points, I'm not sure how to do it. I'm a newbie when it comes to Haskell so any tips would be great.

Comment: Just a comment and not an answer to your question: you mention adding a vector to a point (which makes sense) and then wrote a movePoint function that adds points to points.  I know that Vector and Point are both pairs of Ints, but you'd still be better off defining a different data type for Vector and then writing movePoint :: Point -> Vector -> Point.

Comment: This may just be a typo, but your data declaration needs a constructor. So `data Point = Point {xCoord :: Int, yCoord :: Int}`

Answer (score 7):

Partially apply the `movePoint` function (i.e., call it with fewer arguments than it needs), like this:

```
movePoints pts vec = map (movePoint vec) pts
```

Doing so creates a new function that only needs one argument, the one that you didn't provide the first time. This is known as currying.